# find_or_create_by with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a DB of individuals:

```
First Name
Surname
DOB
```

I want to avoid duplicates when adding new data. I think I need to use `find_or_create_by`. Sometimes, `DOB` is not available. I want to check all three, but if `DOB` is not available (i.e. is null), I want to check just `Surname` and `First Name`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, it might just not be one method chain.

Building your query as a hash is the first way that occurred to me to achieve what you want. Hopefully this should be easy to throw into a model or controller without many changes.

```
query = { first_name: first_name, surname: surname }
query = query.merge(date_of_birth: date_of_birth) if date_of_birth.present?
individual = Individual.find_or_create_by(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add some validations, in your model something like,

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :first_name, :surname, uniqueness: true, if: Proc.new { |a| a.first_name && a.surname}
    validates :first_name, :surname, :date_of_birth, uniqueness: true, if: Proc.new { |a| a.first_name && a.surname && a.date_of_birth}
end
```

[Read more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)